# Hide Product Prices For Users On Specific Category or Categories On WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a code for Hide Product Price for Guest Users not logged in Users but it restricted to all products not specific category some can help me to convert the code to target specific category or Categories

```
// Hide prices
add_action('after_setup_theme','magik_activate_filter') ;

function magik_activate_filter()
{
   add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'magik_show_price_logged');
}

function magik_show_price_logged($price)
{
   if(is_user_logged_in() )
   {
      return $price;
   }
   else
  {
     remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
     remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
     return '<a href="' . get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">Login to order</a>';
  }
}

//Option Two (If you decided to use Option One then don't add the following code)
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'my_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2);
function my_woocommerce_is_purchasable($is_purchasable, $product) {

    $isLoggedIn = is_user_logged_in();
    if(true == $isLoggedIn){
        //Make product purchasable to logged in user
        return true;
    }

    //Make product not purchasable to unlogged in user
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the has_term function to check if a product belongs to a certain category.
Below are the code

```
// Hide prices
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'magik_activate_filter');

function magik_activate_filter() {
    add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'magik_show_price_logged');
}

function magik_show_price_logged($price) {
    global $post;

    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        return $price;
    } else {
        $product_id = $post->ID;
        
        // Check if the product belongs to a specific category or categories
        $target_categories = array('category1', 'category2'); // Replace with your target category or categories
        $has_target_category = false;

        foreach ($target_categories as $target_category) {
            if (has_term($target_category, 'product_cat', $product_id)) {
                $has_target_category = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($has_target_category) {
            remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);
            remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10);
            return '<a href="' . get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">Login to order</a>';
        } else {
            return $price;
        }
    }
}

// Option Two (If you decided to use Option One then don't add the following code)
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'my_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2);

function my_woocommerce_is_purchasable($is_purchasable, $product) {
    $isLoggedIn = is_user_logged_in();

    if (true == $isLoggedIn) {
        // Make product purchasable to logged-in user
        return true;
    }

    // Make product not purchasable to unlogged-in user
    return false;
}
```